# THREE.Audio setRefDistance is not a function

Tags: javascript, audio, three.js

I'm using three r73 and got stuck with a simple 3D audio example:

```
        // ...
        var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
        camera.add( listener );

        var sound1 = new THREE.Audio( listener );
        sound1.load( 'sounds/song.ogg' );
        sound1.setVolume(1);
        sound1.setRefDistance(10);
        sound1.autoplay = true;

        mesh.add(sound1);
```

I got `setRefDistance is not a function`.
If I remove this line `sound1.setRefDistance(10);`, the sound play but isn't "3D aware".

I don't know what is different from this simple example http://threejs.org/examples/misc_sound.html except I'm in an angular context + nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad, I was in fact using r74dev and I needed to use `THREE.PositionalAudio`